# Removing an object by key inside another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an object which is nested in another object by using the sub-object key.

Example:

```
var myMainObj = {
     'subObjA' = {
         'randomstuff' : 1,
         'randomstuff2' : 2,
      },
     'subObjB' = {
         'randomstuff' : 1,
         'randomstuff2' : 2,
     }

}
```

Now how would I go about completely remove the object "subObjB" if I know the keyname of it?

Comment: you couldn't find this out in a web search???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operartor:

```
delete myMainObj['subObjB'];
```

or

```
delete myMainObj.subObjB;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
delete myMainObj.subObjB;
```